# ComboBox binding works only one way with Color property

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox

I'm implementing an `ObservableCollection` <-> `DataGrid` binding.
My class consists of a `System.Windows.Media.Color` field (named 'Color') and several strings.

My implementation in WPF of the Color column:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Color" Width="100">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ColorProperties}}" 
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Color, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                      Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxFlatStyle}">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Rectangle Fill="{Binding}" Height="10" Width="10" Margin="2"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="2,0,0,0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

And ColorProperties:

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="ColorProperties" ObjectType="{x:Type color:ColorHelper}" 
                    MethodName="GetColorNames"/>
```

The ColorHelper class (I'll try to find the OP for credit):

```
public static class ColorHelper
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetColorNames()
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo p
          in typeof(Colors).GetProperties(
          BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static))
        {
            yield return p.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

This works just fine, I can see the combo-box with all the colors:

[image]

Now I added a few objects to the ObservableCollection, and their respective fields are populated in the DataGrid. All except the Color.

The default Color is Black, but when I run the application, the ComboBox stays empty.

When I select a color from the ComboBox, the ObservableCollection changes accordingly. However if I change the object itself, the ComboBox stays with its original value.

For troubleshooting, I added

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Color" Binding="{Binding Color, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" 
                    Width="100"/>
```

This column gets populated with the string representation of the color, and when I change the value from either side, it changes accordingly.
This fact suggests that there's something missing in the ComboBox implementation.

Am I missing some sort of translation method? Seems weird since it actually works in one way (from ComboBox to object).

I've searched everywhere for a solution, without success.

EDIT:
I implemented Color<->String converter, still doesn't work..

```
public class StringToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Color content = (Color)value;

        return content.ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string content = (string)value;

        return (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(content);
    }
}
```

WPF change:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ColorProperties}}" 
                                              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Color, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay, 
                                                             Converter={StaticResource StringToColorConverter}}"
                                              Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxFlatStyle}">
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the `Color` property firing a property change event when it is set?

Comment: Yes, I implemented the interface for INotifyPropertyChange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i found out what was wrong. It looks like getting the actual name from a color is not that simple. ToString returns the hex string, and not the actual color name.
So I used the answer from http://www.blogs.intuidev.com/post/2010/02/05/ColorHelper.aspx to create the converter.

```
public class ColorToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Color KnownColor;

        Color content = (Color)value;

        Type ColorType = typeof(System.Windows.Media.Colors);
        PropertyInfo[] ColorsCollection = ColorType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in ColorsCollection)
        {
            KnownColor = (Color)pi.GetValue(null);
            if (KnownColor == content)
                return pi.Name;
        }

        return String.Empty;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string content = (string)value;

        return (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(content);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The list bound to Combobox is a list of strings, whereas the actual object is not just a string. you need a converter that converts from string to your desired object.

Rest all seems fine, system dosent know how does string Black translates to Color Black

-- one way binding works because, color object knows how to get color from a string, that is why when we set Background="String" it get the corresponding object using FromName

Comment: Hi Muds, thank you for the response. I'm sorry but I'm a bit confused... The combobox is populated with strings, so the Sting->Color conversion works, since selecting a color in the combobox changes the Color property. What's missing is the Color->String conversion, since changes in the property are not reflected in the combobox. Am I correct? I'll edit the post with the converter I implemented. Still doesn't work though..